# How do you unlock the unlockable characters in Pokemon Puzzle League?

Tags: pokemon-puzzle-league

I'm playing the N64 game Pokemon Puzzle League on the Wii (not Wii U), which I downloaded from the Nintendo Channel.  There are several greyed-out characters that I figured out would unlock if I beat things in 1P mode, but I've completed the game on both Easy and Normal mode and nothing has unlocked.

There seems to be very little online about this game.  Several places list certain characters as unlockable, and a few give a code that supposedly unlocks all the unlockable characters, but certainly there's a legitimate way to unlock the characters in the game, right?